# choosed values are resetting in page submit in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't want to rest the selected values from drop down and checked radio button while submitting the form.
In the onclick of both radio button i have to submit the form,after submitting it appears to reset the selected values.
Here is the code am using

```
 <%= form_tag(:action =>"show", :method => "post") do %>
    <%= @name %>.
    <strong>Select device: </strong> <%= collection_select(:device, :id, @devices, :id, :name, options ={:selected => params[:name],:prompt => "-Select a device"}) %>
    <br></br>
    <strong>Chose: </strong>
    <%=  radio_button_tag :name,:time,@name.eql?('time'),:onclick => "this.parentNode.submit();"%>Time

    <%=  radio_button_tag :name,:graph,,@name.eql?('graph') :onclick => "this.parentNode.submit();" %>Graph
    <%end%>
```

After choosing the values in page refresh selected values are showing.But not displaying selected values after the radio button click.

Comment: Can you show the javascript that does the submission?

Comment: javascript is not using for submission.i didnt get what you mean

Comment: what does "this.parentNode.submit()" do?  I don't see an actual submit button, only javascript to do the submission some other way.  That seems to be tied to radio buttons... which is odd.

Comment: in the onclick of radio button "this.parentNode.submit()" will do the form submission.no need to use buttons

Comment: ...and, what does that javascript do?  I don't know what this.parentNode is.

Comment: while calling this this.parentNode.submit() it submits the form

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25332/discussion-between-chinchu-and-bchurchill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the collection_select code to

```
collection_select(:device, :id, @devices, :id, :name, { selected: params.fetch(:device, {})[:id].to_i, :prompt => "-Select a device" }) %>
```

UPDATE: for the radio buttons.

I'm not sure how you are setting `@name` but since you are using that to check the state of the radio button, you should be doing this in the controller

```
@name = params[:name]
```

or if you don't want to do that, you can do the following

```
<%= params[:name] %>.
<%= radio_button_tag :name, :time, params[:name] == 'time', onclick: 'this.parentNode.submit();' %>Time
<%= radio_button_tag :name, :graph, params[:name] == 'graph'), onclick: 'this.parentNode.submit();' %>Graph
```

Comment: but in case of radio button?

Comment: thank u its working in case of dropdown menu..how it is possible in radio button